# How can i render my image value as array from the local storage in function component?

Tags: reactjs

I want to render the image from the local storage folder, i tried with the code below,
but its not working, can someone please help me out.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Post from './Post';
    
function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      imageUrl: require('./img/naso.jpg'),
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      imageUrl: require('./img/bimal.jpg'),
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <Post
          key={post.id}
          imageUrl={post.imageUrl}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I can't figure out where in the code you're getting the image to render

Comment: There isn't any local storage code here. You can't require('..') something in a `useState` initial data. If you just need the imageUrl, why do you call `require`?

Comment: It should be something like `useState([ { imageUrl: '.img/naso.jpg' } ]);` and then in you Post component, `<img src={imageUrl} />`

Comment: bro, i tried it out just like useState([ { imageUrl: '.img/naso.jpg' }]); but it showing the error as TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the image at the top:

```js
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import Post from './Post';

function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([
    ({
       id: 1,
      imageUrl: require('./img/naso.jpg')
    },
    {
      id: 2,
     imageUrl: require('./img/bimal.jpg'),
    })
  ];
  return (
    <div>

      {posts.map((post) => (
        <Post
          key={post.id}
          imageUrl={post.imageUrl}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Good Luck...

Comment: thank you, for the answer sir, i knew it before, but is there any other way without importing the resources in the heading section, can't we link the image to file in its array object itself.

Comment: thanks bro, that tiny missing bracket of useState, caught me the error, any way once again thanks